# How can I get input right when it is typed in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, input, io, buffering

I have written a Brainfuck interpreter in Haskell, but it only operates on the input once I hit Ctrl-D to signal EOF. How can I make the program act on each character when it is typed?

[Here](http://hpaste.org/66134) is the source. To use the program, give a file to interpret as an argument or type your program in the first line of stdin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like your input is being buffered. You can modify the buffering mode of a file handle with `System.IO.hSetBuffering`. If you are reading from standard input, for instance, then you could disable buffering with:

```
import System.IO

hSetBuffering stdin NoBuffering
```

Comment: I tried that, but it still waited until I hit Ctrl-D before giving a response to my input.

Comment: I changed `stdout`'s buffering mode to `NoBuffering`, and that solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

`getLine` waits for a newline character to be typed (`\n`), because what if the user typed a bunch of characters, but never pressed enter? Then it would be an error if some of the "line" had already be processed, if that "line" wasn't a line after all.

You should use `getContents` instead which will return everything that is typed at the terminal.

Also, you are using the following line:

```
then hGetContents =<< openFile (head args) ReadMode
```

This will open a file and never close it. This is fine for your short program, but it might be a better idea for the future to get used to doing this:

```
then readFile $ head args
```

Comment: The problem doesn't lie with the `getLine` at the beginning, but rather with the `getChar` near the end (in the `exec` function).